# Can't install any app, App Store asks for money

Tags: iphone

Now, for every new application, even those free ones,I have to confirm for pay money. And then App Store asks to enter my credit card information. If I disagree and hit "Cancel", installation process is interrupted and I can't install any application, even free one.

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what you mean with "I have to confirm for pay money" when downloading free apps.

If you download free apps and haven't attached a payment method with your Apple ID yet, Apple asks you to do so. Nothing about asking for money. You can still tell Apple to use "None" as a payment method instead of declining the process altogether. As soon as you've done that you should be able to download free apps without getting bugged again.

Also: did you just create the Apple ID or is it an existing one? Please refer to the support article outlining how to use the App Store without a payment method:

[Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account without a credit card or other payment method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034)